# Starting Minishift VM ..... FAIL E1210 : "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"

Tags: okd, minishift

I was trying to install minishift on my local laptop.
I was following the below said steps as part of the process.

https://docs.okd.io/3.11/minishift/getting-started/preparing-to-install.html

1. Set up your virtualization environment
2. Download Minishift software for your operating system from the Minishift Releases page
3. Install Minishift
4. Start Minishift
5. Configure Minishift so you can use it efficiently

I did install VirtualBox (6.1.16) as part of virtualization. And disabled the Hyper-v and Windows Hypervisor platform (Windows Program Features on/off). But after downloading and installing minishift by configuring it under PATH environment variable. I run the the below command - **minishift start** from command prompt.

```
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    4 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Starting Minishift VM ..... FAIL E1210 00:01:26.829916    9000 start.go:499] Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory". Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error creating the VM. Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

I verified the BIOS Setup for VT-x/AMD-v, and it is enabled already, so I am wondering why it is still throwing this error -

> This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I used this commands [cdk-scripts](https://github.com/odockal/cdk-scripts/blob/master/scripts/cdk3-virt.sh#L31) to verify that machine is capable of virtualization before running minishift on it. Should work for win 10 and 7.

Feel free to check the commands out on your machine. You will need powershell for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej. I tried to run the script file provided "cdk3-virt.sh" from powershell , so I was asked to install Windows subsystem for Linux, which I did by installing Ubuntu on Windows 10 Pro but hit with a dependency missing script-utils.sh while executing it. Any additional details much appreciated.

Comment: I was referring to the powershell commands themselves. You can extract them and execute in powershell which would give you basic overview whether you have virtualization set correctly on windows for minishift - this way you do not need to install linux subsystem.
But, if you want to use the whole script, you have to checkout the referenced git repo, cd into scripts directory and then call the script `cdk3-virt.sh`. You need to run it in bash. You can install ie. Git Bash for windows [1].

[1]: https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway

Comment: Thanks Ondrej. Yes, I did follow the first method of extracting the PS commands itself.
That gave me the insight of whether virtualization was enabled. 
I uninstalled the existing virtual box and managed to run the minishift from windows hypervisor option. I adjusted my application processes (to control RAM usage) and launched minshift successfully using available 4GB RAM (out of total 8 GB in my machine).

Answer (score 0):

To answer to my question here -

I uninstalled the existing virtual box and managed to run the minishift from windows hypervisor option (Hyper-v Manager). I adjusted my application processes (to control RAM usage) and launched minshift successfully using available 4GB RAM (out of total 8 GB in my machine).